# woocommerce updating the stock status

Tags: woocommerce

I am updating the stock status with the code below from a different system. but it shows that there is no stock when listing the product. Do I have a mistake in case of stock

```
update_post_meta($id,"_stock",$stok_number);

        if (intval($stok_number) == 0) {
                update_post_meta($id, "_stock_status", "outofstock");
            } else {
                update_post_meta($id, "_stock_status", "instock");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use WC core functions. I assume the $id is a valid product ID:

```
$product = new WC_Product($id);
$product->set_stock_quantity($stok_number);
$stock_status = ($stock_number <= 0) ? 'outofstock' : 'instock';
$product->set_stock_status(stock_status);
$product->save();
```